# Azure Resource Manager: Web App Slots Config: App Service Authentication

Tags: json, azure, web-applications, azure-resource-manager, azure-deployment-slots

I am having a issue with applying a App Service Authentication to my Web App Slots.

The error i am receiving is the following:

**"The template resource 'webapptest1a/authconfig' for type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Frontdoor.Common.Entities.TemplateGenericProperty`1[System.String]' at line '1' and column '8107' has incorrect segment lengths. A nested resource type must have identical number of segments as its resource name. A root resource type must have segment length one greater than its resource name"**

Here is my code, which i think is pretty much correct. I am finding it difficult to find references for Web App slots config. I have the Microsoft Documentation and i followed it, but no luck.

Here is my code:

```
{
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/config",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('webAppName'),'/authconfig')]",
        "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[parameters('webAppName')]",
            "[concat(parameters('sqlDatabase'), 'constr')]"
        ],
         "properties": {
            "enabled": true,
            "runtimeVersion": "~1",
            "unauthenticatedClientAction": "RedirectToLoginPage",
            "tokenStoreEnabled": true,
            "allowedExternalRedirectUrls": null,
            "defaultProvider": "AzureActiveDirectory",
            "clientId": null,
            "clientSecret": null,
            "clientSecretCertificateThumbprint": null,
            "issuer": null,
            "allowedAudiences": [
                "https://webapptest1a-staging.azurewebsites.net"
            ],
            "additionalLoginParams": null,
            "isAadAutoProvisioned": false,
            "googleClientId": null,
            "googleClientSecret": null,
            "googleOAuthScopes": null,
            "facebookAppId": null,
            "facebookAppSecret": null,
            "facebookOAuthScopes": [
            ""
            ],
            "twitterConsumerKey": null,
            "twitterConsumerSecret": null,
            "microsoftAccountClientId": null,
            "microsoftAccountClientSecret": null,
            "microsoftAccountOAuthScopes": [
            ""
            ]
            }
        },
```

I am really concussed, i have tried many variants but i am not getting close.

I changed the name to few different variants then i was given different errors but in regards to the naming convention.

```
"name": "[concat(parameters('webAppName'), '/appsettings')]",
```

**I also changed the Depends on twice from:**

```
"[parameters('webAppName')]",
                "[concat(parameters('sqlDatabase'), 'constr')]"
```

**To:**

```
"[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('webAppName'))]",
            "[concat(parameters('sqlDatabase'), 'constr')]"
```

I am really stuck! Would love some guidance.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says that "**A root level resource must have one less segment in the name than the resource type**". Here you are passing the incorrect name for the resource. As the segment length of **Type** is 4, segment length of **Name** must be 3. So in the config name you must pass the slot name also something like below (You can change the slot name and config name according to your template)

`[concat(parameters('webAppName'), '/staging/web')]`

Please check the below example for reference:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/config",
    "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('webAppName'), '/staging/web')]",
    "location": "East US",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/slots', parameters('webAppName'), 'staging')]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('webAppName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "numberOfWorkers": 1,
        "defaultDocuments": [
            "Default.htm",
            "Default.html",
            "Default.asp",
            "index.htm",
            "index.html",
            "iisstart.htm",
            "default.aspx",
            "index.php",
            "hostingstart.html"
        ],
        "netFrameworkVersion": "v4.0",
        "requestTracingEnabled": false,
        "remoteDebuggingEnabled": false,
        "remoteDebuggingVersion": "VS2019",
        "httpLoggingEnabled": false,
        "logsDirectorySizeLimit": 35,
        "detailedErrorLoggingEnabled": false,
        "publishingUsername": "$mytestap345__staging",
        "scmType": "None",
        "use32BitWorkerProcess": true,
        "webSocketsEnabled": false,
        "alwaysOn": false,
        "managedPipelineMode": "Integrated",
        "virtualApplications": [
            {
                "virtualPath": "/",
                "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot",
                "preloadEnabled": false
            }
        ],
        "loadBalancing": "LeastRequests",
        "experiments": {
            "rampUpRules": []
        },
        "autoHealEnabled": false,
        "localMySqlEnabled": false,
        "ipSecurityRestrictions": [
            {
                "ipAddress": "Any",
                "action": "Allow",
                "priority": 1,
                "name": "Allow all",
                "description": "Allow all access"
            }
        ],
        "scmIpSecurityRestrictions": [
            {
                "ipAddress": "Any",
                "action": "Allow",
                "priority": 1,
                "name": "Allow all",
                "description": "Allow all access"
            }
        ],
        "scmIpSecurityRestrictionsUseMain": false,
        "http20Enabled": false,
        "minTlsVersion": "1.2",
        "ftpsState": "AllAllowed",
        "reservedInstanceCount": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Jagrati - i fixed that error and was greeted with a new error!

"The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/mfrswebapptest1a/slots/slots' under resource group 'MFRS-WEBAPP-AUTH-TEST' was not found."

i know what it's saying, but i don't see where my in code i've declared that...

Comment: Could you please add the template and ask it in another question so that I can look at the template and solve your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Jagrati, i added a new question in regards to this issue - if you want, you can check it out :)